# Error in source ~/.profile

Tags: command-line, bash, .profile, fish

```
~/.profile (line 25): Missing end to balance this if statement
if [ -d "$HOME/local/bin" ] ; then
^
from sourcing file ~/.profile
    called on standard input

source: Error while reading file “/home/user/.profile”
```

Comment: I don't actually see a question, just a statement & cut/paste.  If you `stat ~/.profile` you see when it was last changed & who made the change causing the error (possibly a `fi` (endif) was accidentally deleted or better commended out. Without seeing more of the file I'd not want to say where it needs to be fixed, but I would suggest looking at what was done & correct it.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the reported error, you appear to be sourcing a Bourne-style `.profile` into the `fish` shell:

```
$ fish
Welcome to fish, the friendly interactive shell
Type help for instructions on how to use fish
 ~> 
 ~> source ~/.profile
Missing end to balance this if statement
~/.profile (line 22): if [ -r "$HOME/env_vars" ]; then
                      ^
from sourcing file ~/.profile
    called on standard input

source: Error while reading file “/home/steeldriver/.profile”
```

The conditional syntax is not compatible between the two shell families: see for example [fish Tutorial: Conditionals (If, Else, Switch)](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/tutorial.html#tut_conditionals)